# Haskell Cartesian Product Recursively

Tags: haskell, cartesian-product

I know how to use list comprehension to do this, but how can I implement a function that will recursively compute the cartesian product given two sets?

Here's where I'm stuck (and I'm a noob)

```
crossProd :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
crossProd xs ys | xs == [] || ys == [] = []
                | otherwise = (head xs, head ys) : crossProd (tail xs) (ys)
```

The output of this gives me

> [(1,4),(1,5),(1,6)]

If the sets are `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]` respectively..
How would I go about getting the rest?

Comment: Try writing a simpler case: crossProdAux :: Int -> [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]

Comment: This is most naturally written as **list comprehension**.

Answer (score 4):

The most basic case is this:

```
{-crossProdAux :: Int -> [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]-}
crossProdAux x []    = []
crossProdAux x (a:b) = (x, a):(crossProdAux x b)

{-crossProd :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]-}
crossProd [] ys   = []
crossProd (a:b) ys= (crossProdAux a ys)++(crossProd b ys)
```

Comment: I'm curious, why did you comment out your type signatures?

Comment: Probably because the function works for every type, not just Int.

Comment: Yeah... I didn't want to add imprecise info to the code in my answer (or, more importantly confuse the OP).

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a single function:

```
crossProd :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
crossProd (x:xs) ys = map (\y -> (x, y)) ys ++ crossProd xs ys
crossProd _      _  = []
```

Notice that I've generalised your types so that this works for any `a` and `b`, rather than just `Int`s.

The key to this function is understanding that you want to pair each element in the first list with each element in the second. This solution therefore takes one element `x` from the first list, and pairs it with every one in `ys`. This is done by mapping a function that takes each value `y` from `ys`, and turns it into a pair `(x, y)`. We add this to the front of recursing with the rest of the list `xs`.

In the base case, there is nothing left to pair, so the output is empty.